# PHP's strcmp function giving weird outputs?

Tags: php, strcmp

I have a file called `users.txt`, where I have lots of lines of username and password combinations. Here's an example of this file:

```
kyle:pass1
steve:pass2
john:pass3
ralph:pass4
```

So a username would be `steve` and the password would be `pass1`. These are passed to my file, login.php, via POST. So here's what I've written so far:

```
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$lines = file("users.txt");
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $inputUserInfo = explode(":", $line);
    $inputUsername = $inputUserInfo[0];
    $inputPassword = $inputUserInfo[1];
    if (strcmp($username, $inputUsername) == 0) {
        echo 'username matched!';
    }
    if (strcmp($password, $inputPassword) == 0) {
        echo 'password matched!';
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's happening, but the username matches fine as the method `strcmp` returns 0. Then, when I try to match the password for `steve` and `pass2`, or any other theoretically valid combination, the method `strcmp` returns -2, -1, or anything other than zero.

I really can't tell why this is happening, I've tried everything I can think of. Can anybody tell what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add the flags inside your [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file("users.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

This basically adds that `newline` in your password field. If you examine this carefully, your password has some added newline into it:

```
var_dump($inputPassword);
```

```
string(7) "pass2 
        "
```

Thus the mismatch.

Comment: Useless to have 2 answers saying the same :)

Comment: @Rizier123 didn't expect you were writing one yourself, its just seconds ahead, i was going to upvote regardless since its correct

Comment: Maybe if you want to add this: `echo "<pre>";  
  var_dump(str_replace(PHP_EOL, "&#x00B6;", $lines));` <- With this you can see it very good where the new line characters are

Comment: Ahh, those pesky new line characters, completely forgot about those... Thank you so much!